# How to enable both Passphrase *and* Password+Yubikey as authentication method for a given user account?

Tags: fedora, authentication, session, yubikey, 2-factor-authentication

### Context

I am lazy. But I am also (a bit) concerned with security.

So on my machine (running Fedora), I want to be able to both:

- log into my session using a strong passphrase,
- log into my session using a quick-to-type password when my Yubikey is plugged in.

There are 3 reasons for that:

1. I want to be able to log into my machine with a passphrase only (if I lose my Yubikey, or if I'm comfy in my bed and I don't want to get up grab the Yubikey in my jacket — remember, I'm lazy).
2. Yet if I've my Yubikey plugged in (e.g. at work), I'd like to log in with a quick-to-type password only (remember, I'm  lazy) as I frequently lock my session — and so have to log in back.
3. I wouldn't want to use my Yubikey alone (without password), though, as I might forget to unplug the key when I lock the session (lazy… and concerned about security).

### Question

**How to setup my user account, so I can log in using either of these two different authentication methods?**

- passphrase only,
- password + Yubikey

Comment: FYI, [this piece of documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_Yubikeys_with_Fedora) details how to set up a Yubikey + password authentication. I intend to test it but, by the read of it, it seems that the Yubikey will be _required_, so authenticating through passphrase only wouldn't be available any more (for that user).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution strategy I have come up so far:

1. One can create multiple accounts with same UID (cf. [Why can I create Users with the same UID](https://askubuntu.com/q/427107/498358)) — i.e. both accounts would be the same users from the OS perspective, but we could have a separate authentication method for each (one with passphrase, another with Yubikey + password). Whether it's a good idea [is debated](https://serverfault.com/q/4916).
2. It is possible to [require both a Yubikey and password](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_Yubikeys_with_Fedora#Requiring_both_yubikey_and_password) as authentication strategy. It is defined in  the [Linux PAM](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam.d) system. (It is also possible to require a password only!)

The points I haven't solved so far:

- How to assign a spefic PAM-rule *per account* (cf. point 1 above)?
- How to implement the Yubikey + passphrase authentication strategy in GDM (GNOME Display Manager — i.e. the GUI to authenticate in Fedora)?

(I'll update this post once I've made progress on these issues.)